# Electron change frame on/off from remote

Tags: electron

Can someone tell me if it's possible to toggle frame property of BrowserWindow object using remote ?

I have tried to add this property to remote.getCurrentWindow().setBounds but that doesn't work.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that.

Here's the rejected feature request for this: [github.com/electron/electron/issues/1145](http://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1145)

Quote from zcbenz

> Enabling removing window frame on the fly will add too much complexity
>   to the code, and it is not easy to implement. I don't think it
>   deserves the efforts, even though it is useful in some rare cases.

Nothing changed from that time in this matter

*As it's mentioned in the issue you can work around this by destroying the current window and create an identical with different frame property if that fits for you*