# Electron: Is it possible to set the current window to be frameless?

Tags: node.js, electron

I would like to be able to toggle between framed and frameless window in my Electron app, without needing to construct a new window. This is because this option is a different view than what would be initially loaded, therefore it would be nice if there is a way to change the current window to be frameless.

I have found `window.setFullscreen()` for toggling between full screen mode. I've not been able to find anything similar for frameless window. Is there any such method or workaround that I'm not seeing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300629/electron-change-frame-on-off-from-remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs go, you enable or disable window frame at the time of creation of browser window. After that, there are no methods you can call to enable or disable frame. However, if you **really really** want that option, there may be a workaround. And a workaround, is well, a workaround.

1. Create 2 browser windows, one over the other. The first one being transparent window(with frame and click-through) and the second one being your content window(without frame).
2. Implement your custom solution to keep size and position of both the windows in sync. Use ipc to share data between the windows.
3. Toggle the visibility of the transparent browser window to show/hide frame.

***Some relevant resources:***

Creating frameless window : https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#create-a-frameless-window

Creating transparent window : https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#transparent-window